# How to set maximum allowed ping in matchmaking?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Another Valve game Counter-Strike: Global Offensive allows setting the highest allowed ping for connected servers in options, but I haven't found a corresponding option in the Team Fortress 2 settings or a console command for the game.

I often queue for one map only and am frequently placed to an overseas server with close to 150 ping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're currently able to set this limit by clicking on your own avatar in the "party bar" at the top left of the screen, then it should drop down and present you with a "Matchmaking settings" option.

[image: matchmaking settings gui]

The CVARs for these settings (as of April 2018) are as follows:

```
tf_mm_custom_ping_enabled 1 // enable the custom ping limit
tf_mm_custom_ping 80 // set the ping in ms
```

Comment: Please add the command as well if you know, it is easier to use and can be added to autoexec.

Comment: ...to prevent the game from fiddling with or reseting the value.

Comment: I've been looking around but I haven't yet found the Cvar for that setting.

Comment: @user598527 Found the cvars after digging through tf/cfg files.